# authorize user using wechat php

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, wechat

recently tried to use Wechat authentication for my PHP web application but when i try to get auth token it gives me  Error : {"errcode":50001,"errmsg":"user unauthorized hint: [_ue8GA0843e277]"}

I am calling https://api.wechat.com/cgi-bin/token?grant_type=client_credential&appid=wxa1dc8d55458d****&secret=39efd8a98ae56d4f70842527346a**** to get auth token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Errorcode : 50001 states - Unauthorized access.`

This error will happen when the official wechat account is not verified. After verification only you will be able to get the access to the APIs.

You can easily check this, by accessing the wechat account. Under developer section click on Interface and permission. Here it will provide list of info related to wechat API whether it is "obtained" or "not obtained" under "status". Those that contain the status "Obtained" alone will work and rest wont work.

Comment: I also caught similar problem.
`{"errcode": 50001, "errmsg": "user unauthorized hint: [MLkcBa0110e544]"}`

But I have approve for account.

Comment: In the offical account, can you login and check the interface permissions?

Comment: @AtanovVladimir Once logged into the offical account, in your left section called as "Developer Settings" click on the last navigation item which will show up what are the API interface are available for you to use it. In case if you feel difficult, this is my wechatid: thenna86 ping me on it, will have screen share and help you out.